# How late in the season can you hunt coyote?

Tags: hunting, coyotes

It's currently April and I know that's considered late in the season for hunting coyote. Given that I live in a desert climate, how late can you hunt coyote? Is there a reason why I couldn't hunt them into the summer and other parts of the year? I have already checked with my local/state laws and there are no time limitations on coyotes.

Answer (score 4):

As you have observed, you can legally hunt them year round; You just will not be as successful.  Some times of the year are better than others.  The best season for coyotes is late fall / early winter.  During the warmer months when prey is plentiful they are going to be harder to call.

It all comes down to how successful (or not) you want your hunt to be.